# I am Getting Error while Creating or Sync the project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am facing the error in Android Studio while creating or Sync the existing project. I am a linux user

> Gradle 'MyProject' project refresh failed
>   Error:Read-only file system

Comment: The error itself says `Error:Read-only file system` i.e, you're trying to create a project in a non-writable path/folder. Try to create project inside `/home/<user_name>/some/project/folder/path`

Comment: @Shashanth I solved the problem it was not of Android Studio it was of Linux in /var/lib/sda8 got corrupted, so in boot grub i solved the problem by fixing sd8 partition of my Linux mint

Comment: @Shashanth by the Thank you for your response...

Comment: Glad to here that you solved the error. Consider posting an [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to close this thread/question as solved.